# Расположение элементов меню

Tags: html, css

Верстаю меню такого вида
[image]

```
            <ul class="controls">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button">&nbsp;</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button act"></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button"></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button"></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button"></a></li>
            </ul>
```

не могу понять, почему при добавлении к ul float: left кружки выстраиваются один над другим [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/b7SGz/3/) и как сделать так, чтобы они были расположены в ряд?

в опере отображается как надо, в фф и хроме - нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почти всё правильно только класс **button** и **act** нужно указывать для `<li>` а не для 
`<a>`

Comment: аа, вот оно что. да, так работает. спасибо!)

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы ul располашался по центру страницы? добавление margin: 0 auto; положения блока не меняет( http://jsfiddle.net/b7SGz/6/

Comment: А вот этого я не знаю к сожалению. Скорее всего нужно как-то в процентах задать margin-left и margin-right...
Думаю если сделать margin-left:50% то элемент будет чуть правее середины. Нужно еще будет сделать margin-right:половина_длины_блока_ul; 
Не факт, что это всё сработает...Но по логике должно..

Comment: Да, с margin-left: 40%; более-менее центрируется . спасибо)

Comment: @Heidel, Для того, чтобы отцентрировать ul, есть два варианта (о которых мне известно):
1. задаем элементу ul фиксированную ширину, например - width: 300px, а так же прописываем - 
    
    margin:0 auto;

2. если ширина элемента ul неизвестна, то в стилях для него, прописываем - 

    display: inline-block;, 

а в стилях для его родителя, прописываем - 
    text: align-center;

Comment: Вот, набросал на скорую руку: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/Rswt9/

Comment: ага, понятно. большое спасибо!)